# Jenkins git plugin not connecting to repository

Tags: git, plugins, jenkins

I want to use CI for my Android project. So i installed Jenkins on my system and tried to configure GIT plugin in that but I get below exception

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h https://username@company.com/some/path/android.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://username@company.com/some/path/android.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to onestash.verizon.com:443

Can any one tell me what are the possible reasons to get this error. I am able to access the repository from commandline.

[image: Error during jenkins configuration]

Comment: Have you given access to the project repository against the git credentials which you have added in jenkins?

Comment: I got it resolved. It was proxy issue

Comment: @ShrikanthKalluraya would you document the solution, it'd be nice for other  people having the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your plugin settings.

Follow these steps:-

1. Open jenkins.
2. Click on 'Manage Jenkins'
3. Click on 'Manage Plugins'
4. Click on 'Advanced' tab.
5. Delete the 'Server' and 'Port' textbox.
6. Click on 'Submit' button under 'HTTP Proxy Configuration' section.
7. Click on 'Submit' button under 'Upload Plugin' section.
8. Restart jenkins and observe.